# HiddenType in Symfony Form not Mapping

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm trying to pass a random number to my form and use it as the value of a HiddenType. I'm using `'attr' => [ 'value' => '$options['editId']` to put the value in the textbox but when the form is submitted, the value isn't inserted into the table.

**Listing.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="edit_id")
 */
protected $editId;
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEditId()
    {
        return $this->editId;
    }
    /**
     * @param mixed $editId
     */
    public function setEditId($editId)
    {
        $this->editId = $editId;
    }
```

So I've set the name of the variable to $editId and as far as I know, the variable name is what doctrine uses to map it to the corresponding field (using the field name)

**ListingType.php**

```
    ->add('editId', HiddenType::class, [
      'required' => true,
      'disabled' => true,
      'mapped' => true,
      'attr' => [
        'value' => $options['editId']
      ]
    ])
```

I checked the value of the `editId` textbox and the value is there but it's just not being inserted.

**editId**

```
<input type="hidden" id="listing_editId" name="listing[editId]" disabled="disabled" required="required" value="952726647">
```

Comment: Change to `disabled => false` because disabled inputs are not submitted

Comment: What does the final HTML look like? That would be more helpful in determining why it's not being submitted.

Comment: @SalvatoreQZeroastro if I did that, wouldn't the user be able to change the value before it's submitted?

Comment: Set disabled => false, because  otherwise the value isn't in submitted form.

Comment: isn't it an hidden field? However, an input has to be `readonly` and not disabled to be submitted while not editable

Comment: This is a hidden input, not a textbox. But it doesn't matter. They're just as able to change it whether you make it disabled or not. Don't rely on anything coming from a user to be secure.

Comment: You can't prevent users changing values that are submitted to you. Even if you disable input in the browser, a malicious user can just edit the HTML or make a POST request without visiting the form first. Check the value makes sense after you receive it back.

Comment: `wouldn't the user be able to change the value before it's submitted?` yes in the same way they can change hidden to not hidden, and disabled to not disabled, etc. You have a script somewhere that takes this form in, they can post to that from anywhere in the world, hence the need to validate user input from forms (and anywhere really)